# Get random sample with dynamic n parameter from a grouped dataframe using group key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

I want to extract random samples from a `groupby` data frame object. I'd like to dynamically change the n parameter in the `sample(n="dynamic_value")` function by the `groupby key value`. I didn't come across a question or answer like this.

```
d = {'name': ["n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6"], 'cc': ["US", "UK", "US", "UK", "US", "US"], 'selected_count':[3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3], 'view':[4, 64, 52, 2, 65, 21]}
pdf_candidate_names = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The data frame output looks like this:

```
 name  cc  selected_count  view
0   n1  US               3     4
1   n2  UK               1    64
2   n3  US               3    52
3   n4  UK               1     2
4   n5  US               3    65
5   n6  US               3    21
```

According to the above sample data frame, I'd like to get random rows for the given `cc` using `sample()` and assign the `n` parameter according to the number in `selected_count`.  So, for example; `when the groupby key is US n=3, when it's UK n=1`

I tried below but it didn't work since `x["selection_count"]` is not an integer but a column.

```
pdf_selected_names = pd.concat([
    pdf_candidate_names.groupby("cc").apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=x["selection_count"], weights='views')),
    pdf_candidate_names.groupby("cc").apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=x["selection_count"], weights='views'))
]).sample(frac=1.0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) is only using a fixed `n` parameter, you can use [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) within a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('cc', group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda g: g.sample(g['selected_count'].iloc[0]))
       )
```

output:

```
  name  cc  selected_count  view
3   n4  UK               1     2
2   n3  US               3    52
5   n6  US               3    21
4   n5  US               3    65
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems like what I was looking for was `group_keys` parameter. Because I had tried using `iloc` but it return with error without `group_keys=False`.